# Resize WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics

Have tried searching google but I'm struggling to find an answer to this.

I have a basic WPF application with a few controls on. When I maximise the application the controls on the screen stay the same size and I get a lot of wasted space.

Is there a way to get the controls to grow and shrink dynamically with the size of the main window?

Kind Regards

Ash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set a fixed Height and Width properties for your controls.
Instead set, horizontal and vertical alignment to stretch. And make sure your controls are contained inside an appropriate layout panel.

For example-

Fixed size grid:

```
<Grid Background="Red" Width="50" Height="50"/>
```

Dynamically expending grid:

```
<Grid Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: What would be an appropriate layout panel?

Comment: It depends on the way you want to structure your controls.
Please refer to the following link for available layout types:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/LayoutProperties.html

I generally avoid using StackPanel since it doesn't defines boundaries, and causes issues to the dynamic expansion.

Comment: Instead of me starting a new question would you be able to let me know if its possible to split a grid layout into 3 columns. The firs being a quarter of screen size, the second a half and the third a quarter? If this is possible could you give me the Xaml?

Comment: Yes it is possible.
Just use 
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.25*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

See the following for more details:
http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html#add

Answer (score 2):

what you need is not resize, it's called scaling (or zooming) ;-)

Read this article; the task is very trivial with WPF.

(used to be much more complicated in Windows Forms...).

[UI Scaling (UI Zooming) with WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf.aspx)

basically all you need to add to the XAML is this:

```
 <ScaleTransform 
            CenterX="0" CenterY="0"
            ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
            ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=uiScaleSlider,Path=Value}"
        />
```

after that you can use mouse wheel or a slider or any other way (like in your case detect form maximized), to modify the `Value` of the `ScaleTransform`.

Comment: morely using panels (stack,- dock,- panels etc) helps by Auto width and height scaling through resizing. but the best way is yours.

Comment: Although useful in some specific situations, I would find simple scaled down/up UI components generally annoying. E.g. I want a minimum width/height for my scroll bar. Deciding properly on which exact components can scale up along with restrictions results in a far better resizable UI IMHO.

Comment: I agree that Zooming like that is not the best way in all cases, I was simply answering to the OP question, he said: "Is there a way to get the controls to grow and shrink dynamically with the size of the main window?" I would have suggested something different if he had asked in general and not exactly like that :)

Answer (score 1):

Where there's a will, there's a way. You will have to do some work yourself however, WPF can't automagically decide for you exactly how you want the resizing to be done.

Some relevant sources:

- [Layout containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use content decorator that can stretch and scale a single child to fill the available space - Viewbox .

http://www.wpftutorials.com/2011/04/wpf-viewbox.html

Comment: This link doesn't seem to be reachable anymore. Perhaps you could summarize the information here?

Answer (score 1):

this is no problem. The behavior of your controls depends on the container you use and the Horizontal and Vertical Alignment. For Example, if you use a Grid, a TextBox and a Button with Horizontal and Vertical Alignment: Stretch and width and height auto, the Textfield and Button will grow and shrink dynamically.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <TextBox Margin="8,8,8,104.96" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Height="auto" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <Button Content="Button" Margin="8,0,8,8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="92.96" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a resizable control like Grid and put all the controls in Rows/Columns. Also set HorizontalAlignment to stretch for each control.